# Override core Nginx which is currently installed on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, systemd, nginx

I have been having problems trying to figure out how Nginx was installed on my Ubuntu 16.04 server.

Output of `nginx -v` shows:

The program 'nginx' can be found in the following packages:
 * nginx-core
 * nginx-extras
 * nginx-full
 * nginx-light

I gather that this may mean Nginx wasn't actually installed, and it's using a core version of Nginx that ships with Ubuntu.

I want to initialize Nginx with systemd. Should I try to point my systemd script to the existing install, or install it separately and point to that install? Will there be any conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

That's not actually the output of nginx, that's the message that gets printed when you give it a command it recognizes but isn't installed.  (I get the exact same message, and don't have nginx installed)

Run this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nginx-light
```

I believe nginx includes and installs the systemd script.  You may need to do some configuration of the nginx config file though.

Comment: That's what I keep reading, however, I am using Nginx to serve my web application so it must be installed right? I have a configuration file which points to my application. I'm concerned about installing it from apt-get because of a possible conflict.

Comment: Perhaps you installed it through docker or some other mechanism?